# How can I use work manager in my code - android

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, android-workmanager

This is My Code :

```
 
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.home_activity)
        

        loadProductForTheFirst()


 @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)

    private fun hasNetworkAvilable(context: Context): Boolean {

        val service = Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE
        val manager = context.getSystemService(service) as ConnectivityManager
        val network = manager.activeNetwork
        return (network != null)

    }


    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)

    fun loadProductForTheFirst(){


        swipeRefreshMain.isRefreshing = true
        viewModel.getalldata().observe(this, Observer {

            if (!it.isNullOrEmpty()) {


                recycler_main.apply {


                    layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this@HomeActivity, 2)
                    adapter = RecyclerAdapterMain(it, this@HomeActivity)
                    swipeRefreshMain.isRefreshing = false

                }


            } else {

                if (hasNetworkAvilable(this)) {

                    viewModel.products.observe(this, Observer {

                        recycler_main.apply {

                            layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this@HomeActivity, 2)
                            adapter = RecyclerAdapterMain(it, this@HomeActivity)
                            swipeRefreshMain.isRefreshing = false
                        }
                    })
                    viewModel.setup()
                } else {


                    /// in here if the user not internet for loading the products
                    /// the alert dialog displays .

                    AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Internet State")
                        .setMessage("please turn on your internet connection")
                        .create()
                        .show()

                    /// in here I want a method ( workmanager )
                    // that as soon as the internet be accessible
                    /// my product will be updated .


                }
            }
        })

    }
```

well , For the first time that user open my app need the internet to load product from api .

So I just want the method like WorkManager to check if the intenrnet avalibility is accessible .

And after that my method will be load from api .

I did some search but could'nt find any useful example of work with workmanager.

anyone can help me with this . ?

Comment: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager/

Answer (score 0):

I did this code and work for me .

I put it here if someone looking for this method .

I used work manager to get data from api whenever the network is on .

```
val constraints = Constriants.builder(this)
.setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.Connected)
val workManager : WorkManager = WorkManager.getInstance(this)

val oneRequestWork = OneRequestWorker.build(UploadWorker::class.java)
.setconstrints(constraints)
.build
workmanager.enqueue(oneRequestWork)
```

the Upload worker class :

```
class UploadWorker(context : Context , param : WorkerParameters) : Worker(context , param)

  private val viewModel: ViewModelRoom by lazy {

        ViewModelProvider(
            ViewModelStore(),
            FactoryRoom(RepositoryCart(DataBaseRoom.invoke(applicationContext)))
        )
            .get(ViewModelRoom::class.java)
    }

override fun dowork() : Result {

        return try {

        viewModel.setup()



            Result.success()
        } catch (e: Exception) {

            Result.failure()

        }
```